# How to assign a python variable's value(string) as the value in JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, python

I want to assign the email and password value got from the previous page through Python-CGI to JavaScript variable. When I am doing the following code I am getting the below error,

**CODE:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

email=str(form.getvalue("email")[0])
password=str(form.getvalue("password")[0])

print (email,password)  # email@email.com,123456

print ("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>
      var email=String("""+str(email.strip())+""");
      var password=String("""+str(password.strip())+""");
      alert(email);
      alert(password);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>

""")
```

**ERROR**:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

[error which I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymSWj.png)

Comment: This is terrible security; only use it for toys. (a) The password should never be stored on the server in clear text; (b) the password should never _never_ be sent back to the client, and (c) the password should be properly encoded (my password happens to be `"); alert('you have been hacked'); ("`).

Comment: That said, JavaScript strings need to be surrounded by quotes, just like in Python. The error message makes that quite clear.

Comment: your getting error becuase String function parameter should be string the value your passing is not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
email = 'jack@jack.com'
password = 'secret'
val1 = 133

html  = f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>
      var email='{email.strip()}';
      var password='{password.strip()}';
      var data={{'key1':{val1}}};
      alert(email);
      alert(password);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
"""
print(html)
```

output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>
      var email='jack@jack.com';
      var password='secret';
      var data={'key1':133};
      alert(email);
      alert(password);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In this case when var hello = {key1:"value1",key2:'value2"} is there inside the html variable  in JavaScript , how do i escape it or format it?

Comment: @Guru My answer was updated after your comment above. Feel free to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add quoet/double quote before and after the user input:
because in the end , without adding the '' ,the code will be like this
String(email@gmail.com);
so you have to add a quoet/double quote

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
print ("Content-type:text/html\n\n")
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

email=str(form.getvalue("email")[0])
password=str(form.getvalue("password")[0])

print (email,password)  # email@email.com,123456

print ("""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>
      var email=String('"""+str(email.strip())+"""');
      var password=String('"""+str(password.strip())+"""');
      alert(email);
      alert(password);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>

""")
```

Comment: Note that this is prone to XSS injection without proper encoding/escaping, e.g. as JSON.

Comment: i just answed the question, he has a problem with getting data, so i explain , why the problem happen and how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I am new to this. But when I am executing these as Python-CGI on Apache server, this can be done? since the script is executed on server side on Apache server.